# UPD: React doesn't return HTML elements from functions

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs, return

I need to create a nested accordion menu from JSON in the React.Component. Every key of the object of objects have to be the button which shows nested items on click (if the value is not null). I have two functions that create buttons for keys and hidden divs for values but they don't appear in HTML code.

**menuItems.json**

```
{
  "item1": {
    "nestedItem1": null,
    "nestedItem2": {
      "deeplyNetstedItem1": null
    }
  },
  "item2": null,
  "item3": null,
  "item4": {
    "nestedItem3": null
  }
}
```

**DropdownList.jsx (UPD)**

```
import React from "react";

class DropdownList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: this.props.data
    };
    this.createListData = this.createListData.bind(this);
    this.createButton = this.createButton.bind(this);
    this.createHidden = this.createHidden.bind(this);
  }

  createButton = (item) => {
    return <button className='accordion'>{item}</button>
  }

  createHidden = (item) => {
    return <div className='panel'>{item}</div>
  }

  createListData = (data) => {
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
      if (value && typeof(value) == "object") {
        console.log(key, value);
        this.createButton(key);
        this.createListData(value);
      } else {
        this.createHidden(key);
        console.log(key);
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.createListData(this.state.data)}</div>
  }
}

export default DropdownList;
```

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import DropdownList from "./DropdownList/DropdownList";
import data from "./menuItems.json";

function App() {
  return <DropdownList data={data} />;
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
renderObject = obj => {
    return obj === 'object' ? Object.values(obj).map(val =>
      typeof val === 'object' ? (
        this.renderObject(val)
      ) : (
        <li>{val ? val : 'Any message'}</li>
      ),
    ) : <li>Any message</li>
  };
  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderObject(this.state.data)}</div>;
  }
```

Comment: i need to output all items from object, this way outputs only keys

Comment: Okay so try this
`renderObject = obj => {
    return Object.values(obj).map(val =>
      typeof val === 'object' ? (
        this.renderObject(val)
      ) : (
        <li>{val ? val : ''}</li>
      ),
    );
  };
  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderObject(this.state.data)}</div>;
  }`

Comment: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: I updated the above code try that, it will not give you error